# I need to reinstall GDM every boot on 16.04 to get rid of "low memory mode". How can I fix this permanently?

Tags: boot, graphics, lightdm, amd-graphics, gdm

I got a new laptop and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. The bad news is that this computer comes with those switchable graphics things (AMD/Intel). Long story short, I had to change my kernel a bunch of times to the latest build (currently at 4.9.0-040900) until I found one that doesn't crash all the time and lets me put the laptop on standby mode.

But now every time I reboot or shutdown instead of putting the OS to sleep, I boot to that "Low memory mode" screen. The only solution I found to this is opening a console and reinstalling GDM from a .deb that is already saved offline for this purpose.

I believe it has something to do with the GDM/LightDM config files. I've been looking for a solution in forums and chatrooms since November. Can you help me?

Some specs:

```
product: Inspiron 5548 (Inspiron 5548)
vendor: Dell Inc.
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz 64 bits
RAM: 16GiB
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: HD Graphics 5500
vendor: Intel Corporation
*-display
description: Display controller
product: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
```

Comment: What are the specs of your computer ? Please update your question with hardware info.

Comment: This might be a case where the newest possible version might work better than 16.04.1 LTS: I suggest that you try with 16.10 and the daily iso file of the still developing version Zesty Zapus, http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/369/builds